# If/Else hangs when trying to respond with different values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I have a method which searches a file for a term and then returns the entire line as a JSON object. For some reason, when I add the `else` portion of the logic, I get the following error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/vagrant/node_modules/express    /lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/vagrant/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:551:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/vagrant/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:138:14)
    at /home/vagrant/routes/service.js:18:13
    at /home/vagrant/model/instance_map.js:22:17
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

If I remove the `else` statement from below it works, unless the route isn't matched and then the app just hangs unless I add a timeout:

```
exports.mapData = function(instance, instance_map) {

    //read the file and return the matched array
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'../instance-map'), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }

        for (line of splitFile(data))
            if(line.match(instance)) {

                // this is the asynchronous call
                instance_map(convertToJSON(line));

            } else {
                instance_map(instance);
            }

    })
}
```

It looks like this error pops up a lot when trying to call `res()` twice but I am not doing anything like that. Not entirely sure where this error would occur. The actual route which calls the method is as follows:

```
router.get('/mapinfo/:instance_id', function ( req, res, error) {
    file_map.mapData(req.params.instance_id, function (instance_map) {
        res.send(instance_map);
    });
});
```

The idea is to match the last parameter to the contents of a file and return the json. I am new to nodejs so there is probably something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if...else` is inside a for loop.  So `res.send()` may be called several times.

Comment: Well I feel stupid haha. I was also sending a response not matter what. I changed it so the if/else alters a variable within method scope. I think I was so caught up with callbacks and that new way of looking at my code that I wasn't really looking in front of my face.

Answer (score 0):

When you get into the else statement you send to your callback function the "req.params.instance_id".

If your instance_id in the req is Number it will not work:

"The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array."

[Express res.send](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send)

Also as Igal says, you have for loop, and your for loop looks pretty weird.

Comment: Yes I realized almost immediately after reading this post that my loop has all sorts of errors. should have caught that earlier